# howto revert apc 3.1.12 to 3.1.11

Tags: php, ubuntu, apc

After 3.1.12 upgrade, apc.php very soon showed 100% cache used. Soon after, httpd had consumed all physical memory and the systems were swapping. according to [this bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62863),its correct if I Revert APC to 3.1.11. So how can I revert it to 3.1.11?

os:debian sqeeze 6.0.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have followed these steps already:

```
$ wget http://pecl.php.net/get/APC-3.1.11.tgz
$ tar xvzf APC-3.1.11.tgz
$ cd APC-3.1.11
$ /usr/local/bin/phpize
$ ./configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/bin/php-config
$ make
$ make install
```